# Does 1 English letter = 1 Chinese character?

Tags: html, unicode, character-encoding

I am a UX designer and we are working on a product where there needs to be a **text input field** for the user to insert their note. There needs to be a **word limit indication**, whether they're typing in Traditional Chinese or English.

[image: Input text field_with character limit_example]

So my question is:

If the character limit is 15, am I correct to say:

- `I am in Sweden` (11/15 characters)
- `我在瑞典` (4/15 characters)

I was told that 1 Chinese character counts as 2-byte code and 1 English letter counts as 1-byte. How does this affect the character limit? I want to make sure my design is clear as possible for the developers.

Comment: You mean a character limit, not a word limit, right? The answer depends on why you have a character limit in the first place.

Comment: I agree with Ry an both points. Also, what do you want to do if someone puts in a four byte character?

Comment: do you care about how much storage it takes or how much space to show it ?

Comment: "Character limit" is vague.  Are you counting Unicode code points, graphemes, encoded bytes (and what encoding)?  For example, 瑞典 is one Chinese word, two Unicode code points, 4 bytes encoded in UTF-16LE, 6 bytes encoded in UTF8.  `resumé` is considered an English word, but is 6 or 7 Unicode code points, 12 or 14 bytes in UTF-16LE, and 7 or 8 bytes in UTF-8, depending on `é` being a composed or decomposed character.

Comment: Thank you guys!

So basically, this is a SaaS manager. In the invoicing flow, the user can add a note, and the note is going to be applied to the print out invoice. We want to limit the content, otherwise it will fill up the whole page. 

So roughly we want to limit it to 250 words (Chinese and English)

Answer (score 1):

So it’s about display size, right? Counting words won’t be useful in that case because a word can be as long as you want.

Counting characters is marginally more useful, but also doesn’t guarantee that the message will fit in the end because different characters have different widths. Just as an example, these four strings all consist of five characters each:

- “​​​​​”
- “     ”
- “WWWWW”
- “﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽”

There really is no elegant way to solve this. You’d need to know the precise metrics of the font you’re using and then calculate the visual width of each input.

If you’re fine with a “close enough” solution, you can just use the `<input>` element’s `maxlength` attribute. HTML and JavaScript count UTF-16 code units, however, which means that characters in the so-called Basic Multilingual Plane count as 1 and everything else counts as 2.

The Basic Multilingual Plane contains 99% of all characters in common, present-day use, so the vast majority of users probably won’t notice anything wrong. You could do something fancier with JavaScript, but I reckon it’s not really necessary for this kind of task.

Just keep in mind that this approach still won’t guarantee that the user’s input will fit *visually* on the print-out unless you leave a lot of empty room just in case. Definitely play around with some narrow and wide characters to see how much space they really take up when printed.